# Автогенерация типов Typescript

Tags: javascript

Изучаю тайпскрипт и делая очередную задачу, задумался.
Есть такой объект

```
const obj = {
  firstValue: {
   type: 'string'
  },
  secondValue = {
   type: 'boolean'
  }
}
```

Такой просто объектик, и например какой то класс в который мы передаем этот объект, сразу напишу что у класса есть методы описывать я их не буду (если надо будет опишу) но по названию понятны :)

```
const myClass = new Class(obj)
// метод который вернет поле по ключу
class.getValue('firstValue')
```

И собственно вопрос! Можно ли сделать так, что бы в методе getValue мне не позволило взять что-то другое, чего нет в объекте который мы передаем, то есть я бы не смог взять `thirdValue` ну и знать его тип по полю `type`? Понимаю что можно сделать interface и описать его, но вот вопрос в том что хотелось бы динамически прокидывать подобные объекты.
Заранее спасибо за ответ!
P.S вообще не уверен возможно ли это, но я только учусь)

**UPD: Пока писал вопрос ответил на свой вопрос, всем спасибо! Весь ответах был в дженериках**

Comment: ты хочешь ключ передавать? или что? Пока не совсем понятно зачем тебе `type`

Comment: можно, прочитай главу про дженерики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так.
Пример содержит и **getValue** и **setValue**.

```
class GenericClass<T> {
  obj: T;

  constructor(payload: T) {
    this.obj = payload;
  }

  getValue<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    return this.obj[key];
  };

  setValue<K extends keyof T, P extends T[K]>(key: K, newValue: P) {
    this.obj[key] = newValue;
  };
}

const superObj = {
  first: 1,
  second: '2'
}

const superClass = new GenericClass(superObj);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129931/discussion-on-answer-by-----typescript).